# Show counts of drag items in VUE draggable for Nested Item List

Tags: vue.js, draggable

I Want to show counts of drag items while dragging items in VUE draggable for Nested Item List.
When I drag the particular item of lists or items with subitems, at the same time it must show count that how much items I am dragging to another place.

[This is screenshot when I am dragging items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6XfT.png)

Comment: could you add some code snippet to be more clear?

Comment: you can refer this https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-sortable/

Comment: could you catch the drag event?

Answer (score 0):

The onMove event should catch every moved item, use that to up your total drag count. You can also pass the event argument if you want more information of the move event in your method.

```
   methods: {
     onMove: function(event) {
       this.dragcount++
     }
   }
```

Refer to the documentation the vue library is wrapping, it's all in [here](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable).

Comment: It's not working. I am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable for drag.